# ajax post always null on the controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a large knockout array I want to pass to a controller.  To do this I am using an Ajax post statement to a controller.  Every time the form body is posted to the controller it shows as null, even though I see it sending data.

bd  is the knockout array

Ajax Post

```
function xhr_post(url, datap) {
    //console.log(url);
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
      //  async: true,
        dataType: 'text',
     //   headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        data: datap
    })
};
```

Javascript call

```
xhr_post(publish + "api/fileapi/runStep", { e: JSON.stringify(b[d]() )}).done(function (allData) {

});
```

Controller

```
ObjectContext context = new ObjectContext("name=POC_db");

 [HttpPost]
 public void runStep([FromBody]string e) {
   var sql = e;
   var i =  context.ExecuteStoreCommand(sql);
 }
```

Form Data

```
Form Data
e:"this is the code going to the sql server\n"
```

Comment: Huh! Sending SQL from website to execute it directly on your server. This is really a very bad practice.

Comment: @CodeNotFound - Thank you for the comment.  I am aware of the risk that this example appears to demonstrate.  Do you have any information on the issue I am having?

Comment: Make a screen capture of the data sent to your server. I mean F12 on your browser then Network and show us the body content of your POST request

Comment: @CodeNotFound Added the form Data from the post

Comment: Have you tried using application/json and pass in the body a json data { e: 'your_text" } ?

Comment: Use application/json as dataType